# Run a list of String through a list of filters

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have `List<String>` and `List<Filter>`.

```
public interface Filter{
     List<String> filter(List<String> strToFilter);
}
```

How can I pass the `List<String>` through the list of filters and use the output of one filter as an input to the other filter? I can do this using for-loop. I wanted to know how to achieve this using java 8 stream and lambda

Comment: While this is doable with streams, I doubt you'll find anything cleaner than a simple `for (Filter filter : filters) strings = filter.filter(strings);`

Comment: There seems to be confusion as to what you mean by "filter". Please clarify if your use of the word "filters" means a series of *tests* that each string must pass, or a series of *transformations* that is performed on each String with the result of each transformation being passed to the next.

Comment: Does my solution answer your question? If so, please accept solution

Comment: do you actually mean `List<Predicate>` instead of `List<Filter>`?

Comment: Bohemian, you're right when you said these filters are tests that the strings must pass. There is not transformation happening

Comment: I know for-loop would be the cleanest version to do this, but I'm new to stream and lambda and I was curious on how to do this without for-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can chain a `List<Filter>` and apply them to a `List<String>` using streams:

```
List<String> strings = ...
List<Filter> filters = ...

strings = filters.stream()
        .reduce(s -> s, (a, b) -> s -> b.filter(a.filter(s)))
        .filter(strings);
```

But as I mentioned in the comments, I think the cleanest solution is a simple `for` loop:

```
for (Filter filter : filters) {
    strings = filter.filter(strings);
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. So you construct a chained function...and then call that function which will ripple through the entire chain calling each function from the start to finish...that's something else

Comment: @shmosel wouldn't you be able (in case `Filter` is actually a `Predicate`) to reduce the predicates to a single one via `reduce(x -> true, Predicate::and)`

Comment: @Eugene Sure, but what makes you think `Filter` might be a `Predicate`?

Comment: @shmosel it's it obvious from the names? that's the very first thing I thought when reading this

Comment: @Eugene I'll admit the name is confusing (maybe it's something like a [servlet filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)?) but the method signature is not really subject to interpretation...

Comment: @shmosel it might be... good point. but then applying a `String` through this  filters makes absolutely no sense

Comment: @Eugene It's basically a chain of `UnaryOperator<List<String>>`. What exactly doesn't make sense?

Comment: @shmosel my bad - it does not make sense to filter a `String` via a `servlet filter` - this is what I meant.

Comment: @Eugene Of course, I was just borrowing the looser interpretation of "filter" as something that alters rather than strictly reduce. Another example might be a lens filter.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the function api is using "functional interfaces" which represent operations, similar to methods. In this case, a `Predicate<T>` represents an operation which acts on `T` and returns a `boolean`, which is what the `Stream#filter` method requires. So instead of having something which filters your list for you, you can simply have a `Predicate<T>` which filters a `Stream<T>` (from your list):

```
//in our example, 'T' will be a String
List<Predicate<String>> filters = Arrays.asList(s -> s.startsWith("Hello"));
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("Test", "Hello world");
//because we have a list of predicates, we need to apply the #filter for each one
for (Predicate<String> pred : filters) {
    stream = stream.filter(pred);
}
stream.forEach(System.out::println); //prints "Hello world"
```

This can be chained similarly if you don't require storing a list of them:

```
Stream.of("Test", "Hello world")
    .filter(s -> s.startsWith("Hello"))
    .filter(s -> s.length() > 5)
    .forEach(System.out::println); //prints "Hello world"
```

Achieving the application of the `List<"Filter">` isn't too viable with lambdas themselves, the lambdas need variables to be (effectively) final if they exist outside the scope of the lambda.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Sure it does, I stated that using java's `stream`/lambdas isn't a viable use-case for when you have a list of stream operations. This is intended to moreso clear that up for the OP, hence "instead of".

Comment: Well, you did now. But that's still a non-answer and inaccurate.

Comment: What's inaccurate? If op wants to manually pass a list (and not its members which I assumed he is streaming over) through stream operations multiple times, then the reassignment of the list will mean that he cannot pass it into a lambda. Attempts to work around that will be much longer (and potentially, but not always less efficient) than the simple for loop he'd actually need.

Comment: It's not very difficult with a stream. I'm happy to demonstrate if the question is reopened. [I did mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340510/run-a-list-of-string-through-a-list-of-filters#comment81634349_47340510) that I think a for loop is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Are you thinking of using the `#reduce(UnaryOperator<T>)`?

Comment: Along those lines.

Comment: I think I know what you're going for, though it's pretty evil from a readability standpoint lol

Comment: I don't disagree, but I think it's the closest solution to what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have lists like these:

```
List<String> myStrings;
List<Filter> myFilters;
```

So now you do:

```
List<String> myFilteredStrings = myFilters
    .stream()
    .reduce(new ArrayList<String>(myStrings), (strings, filter) -> filter.filter(strings), (l1, l2) -> {
        List<String> combined = new ArrayList(l1);
        combined.addAll(l2);
        return combined;
});
```

If you have access to guava library, you can use [`Iterables.concat`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-) and [`Lists.newArrayList`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList-java.lang.Iterable-) to make it cleaner

```
List<String> myFilteredStrings = myFilters
        .stream()
        .reduce(Lists.newArrayList(myStrings), (strings, filter) -> filter.filter(strings), (l1, l2) -> Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.concat(l1, l2));
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: @shmosel, it should now

Comment: You're misusing `reduce()`. `myStrings` is not a valid *identity*.

Comment: @shmosel "misusing" reduce? I don't understand what you mean. There is no (special) requirement on the `identity` parameter

Comment: Sure there is. Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @shmosel, yes, `@param identity the identity value for the combiner function`. Can you just explain what you actually mean, this cryptic analysis is simply unnecessary

Comment: I was referring to this: *The `identity` value must be an identity for the combiner function. This means that for all `u`, `combiner(identity, u)` is equal to `u`. Additionally, the `combiner` function must be compatible with the `accumulator` function; for all `u` and `t`, the following must hold: `combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t)) == accumulator.apply(u, t)`*

Comment: @shmosel, I'm stumped on that one. How is it possible that for all `u`,`combiner(identity, u)` is equal to `u`? Does the "equal" refer to the `==` or the `equals` method? If the latter, does that mean the combiner is simply supposed to return `u`? If so, what then is the purpose of having it in the first place? If the former, i.e. referring to `==`, then I think that's a pretty weak constraint to impose. I mean what if I am using immutable `u`?

Comment: It means `equals()` when dealing with reference types. The purpose is to provide a seed value that doesn't impact the calculation. For example, 0 is an identity for a sum, and 1 is an identity for a product.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your transformations to a single one, and apply that to each element:

```
List<String> filter(List<String> strToFilter) {
    List<Function<String, String>> transformations; // populate as you wish
    Function<String, String> reduction = transformations.stream().reduce(identity(), (a, b) -> a.andThen(b));
    return strToFilter.stream().map(reduction::apply).collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: Who said it's possible to transform at the element level? It could be reordering, adding, removing, etc.

Comment: @shmo then the Q must be closed pending more info

Comment: Again? I don't know what's so complicated. Did you see my answer?

Comment: Are you stuck on the word "filter"? Look at the signature. It's just a chain of list transformations.

Answer (score -1):

A "filter" is a `Predicate`, so just chain them up:

```
List<String> filter(List<String> strToFilter) {
    return strToFilter.stream()
        // these predicates are just examples
        .filter(s -> s.contains("foo"))
        .filter(s -> s.length() > 5)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: The name is misleading. It's more like a `UnaryOperator`. Anyway, I think you misunderstood the requirement. OP needs to chain a `List<Filter>` and apply it to a `List<String>`.

Comment: How is it misleading? A `UnaryOperator` takes an input and produces an output, which would be correct if op actually had to transpose a list. In this case, he just needs a basic stream filter.

Comment: @Rogue How do you know that? OP never said what the filters are actually doing.

Comment: @shmosel well Rogue's answer assumes the same interpretation as this answer. How can you be sure what OP wants? (btw I have closed the question asking for clarification)

Comment: *How can I pass the List<String> through the list of filters and use the output of one filter as an input to the other filter... using java 8 stream* - that seems pretty clear to me, though admittedly the question could be improved.